# Add Keith Wood Datepicker to Dynamic Knockout List

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datepicker, selectlist

I'm trying to add a Keith Wood Date Picker to a Knockout Dynamic List
I've created a JS Fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/ELTfx/5/

I've created a unique ID for each input box that is created:

Knockout:

```
self.departureDateUniqueID=ko.observable("depDate"+ counter++);
self.departureDateUniqueIDHash = ko.computed(function () {
        return "'#" + self.departureDateUniqueID() + "'";
    });
```

HTML:

```
            <td><input data-bind="value: departureDate,attr: { 'id': departureDateUniqueID }" /></td>
```

I've then attempted to bind the datepicker to the object everytime a new entry is created in the list:

```
    // Operations
    self.addSeat = function() {
    var seat = new SeatReservation("", self.availableMeals[0]);
    self.seats.push(seat);
    alert (seat.departureDateUniqueIDHash());

    $(seat.departureDateUniqueIDHash()).datepick({
        autoSize: true, defaultDate: 0, selectDefaultDate: true,
        onSelect: function (dates) {
            var minDate = dates[0];
            seat.departureDate($.datepick.formatDate(minDate));
        }
    });
}
```

Alas however it's not working.
I'm getting the error 
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#depDate0'

I'm guessing that JQuery hasn't got it in it's DOM yet.

Now I've googled this and various posts recommend the On clause.. but I can't quite figure out how to use it here.

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Is that an auto-correct error in the title, or has the former Irish rugby international really written a date picker?

Comment: Different Keith Wood! http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing... 
you had unnecessary `'` in creating id...

```
self.departureDateUniqueIDHash = ko.computed(function () {
        return "#" + self.departureDateUniqueID() + "";
    });
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ELTfx/6/)**